# How to use Buffer Browserify in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I want to use [Buffer-Browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer-browserify) or this [Buffer](https://github.com/feross/buffer) module in Browser.
I already use the browserify command like this

```
  browserify index.js -o buffer.js
```

after that,  i put in the index.html like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="buffer.js"></script>
```

and then in my javascript code i use it like this

```
  function toBuffer(ab) {
     var buffer = new Buffer(ab.byteLength);
     var view = new Uint8Array(ab);
     for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) {
         buffer[i] = view[i];
     }
     return buffer;
  }
```

But when i run it, it always error : Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined

what is the proper way to use the module ?

Comment: What is in your `index.js` file?